# How to add a List to HBox in JavaFX?

Tags: list, javafx, javafx-2, hbox

Am trying to read some values from database and display it in a List.

```
list = new List();
list.setSize(30, 280);

 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("select subname from subject");
        rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            subject = rs.getString("subname");
            list.add(subject);
        }
  }
```

The import statement for List is-

```
import java.awt.List;
```

So I think List control is not available in JavaFX.

I tried to place the List in HBox -

```
    hb.getChildren().addAll(addSubName, list, b2);
```

Then I got an error -

```
method addAll in interface ObservableList<E> cannot be applied to given types;
required: Node[]
found: TextField,List,Button
reason: varargs mismatch; List cannot be converted to Node
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in interface ObservableList
```

Is this error correctable ? If not, tell me about a control that can be used as a substitute for List in JavaFX.

Comment: Use JavaFX listview instead of AWT. why you use awt's List?

Comment: @JavaMan Thanks for that. What should I use instead of add() and getSelectedItem() methods ?

Comment: They have already method in it for your requirement. the name may be change.

Comment: Did you read the [dcos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)? Or the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF)?